# d3 convert to number in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I have a dataset like this:

```
var data = [{state: "CA", number: "3"},{}...];
```

I want to get the max number in the dataset by using this:

```
d3.max(data, function(d){ return d.number;})
```

However I'm not getting the right answer. Any suggestions on how to correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you are comparing **strings**, and the result may not be what you expect.

For instance, check this demo:

```js
var data = [{
  state: "CA",
  number: "3"
}, {
  state: "NY",
  number: "5"
}, {
  state: "PA",
  number: "41"
}];

var max = d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.number;
});

console.log("Max is: " + max)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

You may think that the maximum is `41`. However, it returns `"5"`, which is indeed the "highest" string.

**Solution**: convert your strings to numbers (here, using the unary plus operator, `+`):

```js
var data = [{
  state: "CA",
  number: "3"
}, {
  state: "NY",
  number: "5"
}, {
  state: "PA",
  number: "41"
}];

var max = d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return +d.number;
  //     ^--- unary plus
});

console.log("Max is: " + max)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```